# Openni2 problem with registered depth points

Tags: ros, xtion, depth-registered, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an Xtion depth camera attached to nao robot, and I try to get registered depth points from it but the topic almost publishes nothing (except one or two messages after long time), also I receive the following warnings:

[ WARN] [1399651428.960430364]: [image_transport] Topics '/xtion/depth_registered/image_raw' and '/xtion/depth_registered/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:

```
Image messages received:      5
CameraInfo messages received: 22
Synchronized pairs:           0
```

[ WARN] [1399651438.444702040]: [image_transport] Topics '/xtion/rgb/image_color' and '/xtion/rgb/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:

```
Image messages received:      4
CameraInfo messages received: 22
Synchronized pairs:           0
```

Note: I run openni2 on the robot just to load the driver and to publish tf, and I run other openni2 on remote PC to do the processing.

Note: I have tried to subscribe to raw rgb image (rostopic hz /topic_name ) and it works correctly alone, and to subscribe to depth raw image and also it works correctly alone, but when I subscribe to both of them in parallel only one of the works.

Can anyone help me, I am new to ros and openni2 and these stuff.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163236/openni2-problem-with-registered-depth-points/) by [abd_el_mon3em](https://answers.ros.org/users/15516/abd_el_mon3em/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Ubuntu 14.04 - ROS Indigo

This is because the depth_registration option is not selected.

Start rqt_reconfigure

```
rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
```

Select the driver from the left side and activate the depth_registration option.

You should now be able to see the registered rgbd pointcloud in rviz.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) with karma: 403 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0